# Spark 2.2 Illegal pattern component: XXX java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: XXX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to upgrade from Spark 2.1 to 2.2. When I try to read or write a dataframe to a location (CSV or JSON) I am receiving this error:

```
Illegal pattern component: XXX
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: XXX
at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.parsePattern(FastDatePrinter.java:282)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.init(FastDatePrinter.java:149)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.<init>(FastDatePrinter.java:142)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.<init>(FastDateFormat.java:384)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.<init>(FastDateFormat.java:369)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat$1.createInstance(FastDateFormat.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat$1.createInstance(FastDateFormat.java:88)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FormatCache.getInstance(FormatCache.java:82)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.getInstance(FastDateFormat.java:165)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JSONOptions.<init>(JSONOptions.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JSONOptions.<init>(JSONOptions.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat.inferSchema(JsonFileFormat.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:177)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:177)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:176)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:333)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:279)
```

I am not setting a default value for dateFormat, so I'm not understanding where it is coming from.

```
spark.createDataFrame(objects.map((o) => MyObject(t.source, t.table, o.partition, o.offset, d)))
    .coalesce(1)
    .write
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .partitionBy("source", "table")
    .json(path)
```

I still get the error with this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark2.2Test").master("local").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val agesRows = List(Person("alice", 35), Person("bob", 10), Person("jill", 24))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(agesRows).toDF();

df.printSchema
df.show

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv("my.csv")
```

Here is the schema:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = false)
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. can you please share MyObject class definition? Try to convert object manually to json then try to save as string

Comment: case class MyObject(source: String, table: String, partition: Int, offset: Long, updatedOn: String)

Comment: Read and write date fields as String. Operate on date field manually using SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found the answer.

The default for the timestampFormat is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` which is an illegal argument. It needs to be set when you are writing the dataframe out.

The fix is to change that to ZZ which will include the timezone.

```
df.write
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ")
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.csv("my.csv")
```

Comment: Also if you're trying to read a file: `df = spark.read.option('timestampFormat', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ').json(PATH_TO_FILE)`

Comment: Correct, this only happens for CSV and JSON.

Comment: Oddly ... I have no timestamps in my output. There is a timestamp column in the prior-to-filtering stages, but still this option was required to avoid the stackdump.

Answer (score 26):

Ensure you are using the correct version of commons-lang3

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: why commons-lang3 have something to do here ?

Comment: I'm also interested by an explanation

Comment: In CDH, hive-exec-1.1.0-cdh5.15.1.jar also has the class "FastDateFormat" which is not supporting the default format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" of org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JSONOptions. So ensure  commons-lang3.3.5 jar is in your classpath. In SBT add dependency with compile option. "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.5" % "compile"

Answer (score 4):

Use commons-lang3-3.5.jar fixed the original error. I didn't check the source code to tell why but it is no surprising as the original exception happens at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.parsePattern(FastDatePrinter.java:282). I also noticed the file /usr/lib/spark/jars/commons-lang3-3.5.jar (on an EMR cluster instance) which also suggest 3.5 is the consistent version to use.

Answer (score -2):

I also met this problem, and my solution(reason) is:
Because I put a wrong format json file to hdfs. 
After I put a correct text or json file, it can go correctly.

Comment: There were no timestamps in the file, just epochs, which are longs. Thanks for the comment.