# Pyspark2 Writing to CSV Issue?

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I am running a py file through the command:

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/bin/spark2-submit --jars /home/jsonnt200/geomesa-hbase-spark-runtime_2.11-1.3.5.1cc.jar,/ccri/hbase-site.zip geomesa_klondike_enrichment2.py
```

This results in the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/jsonnt200/geomesa_klondike_enrichment2.py", line 6306, in
>   
>       df2_500m.write.option('header', 'true').csv('/user/jsonnt200/klondike_201708_1m_500meter_testEQ_union4')
>   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.171658/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py",
>   line 711, in csv
>       self._jwrite.csv(path)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.171658/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call**   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.171658/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 79, in deco
>       raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace) pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'Illegal pattern
>   component: XXX'

The biggest concern is if I submit this same py file through ipython, it runs correctly. Any ideas on what could be the issue? Unfortunately, I have to use the spark2-submit for tunnelling purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **Spark 2.2.0**, right? I have encountered the same issue when trying to read a csv file. The problem, I think, is the `timestampFormat` variabel. Its default value is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX.` Ref. [pyspark.sql documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html).

When I change it to e.g. `timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"`, my code works. This issue is also mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429616/spark-2-2-illegal-pattern-component-xxx-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-ill). Hope it helps :).

Comment: I saw that post as well and tried that solution. It did not work for me though, but that seemed expected to me since I don't have any time stamp columns in my data. Did you have timestamp columns in yours?

Comment: It will fail anyway, since the default value for the `timestampFormat` is wrong. I only have datetype columns. Do you get the same error if you change the format value?

Comment: Yea, I tried yours just in case and don't receive the same error, I just receive a generic failure error now. `File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o128.csv.`