# How to chose a specific version of package added by different SBT library dependencies

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, sbt

I'm developing Apache Spark application on Scala 2.11 using SBT 1.3.10. I use IDE on my local machine without having Spark/Hadoop/Hive installed, but rather added them as SBT dependencies (Hadoop 3.1.2, Spark 2.4.5, Hive 3.1.2). My SBT is below:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.1.2",

  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.10",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.10",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.9.10",


  // about these two later in the question
  "org.apache.hive" % "hive-exec" % "3.1.2",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.6"
)
```

In my application I'm reading a sample CSV file into DataFrame with provided schema:

```
        val init = spark.read
          .format("csv")
          .option("header", value = false)
          .schema(sampleCsvSchema)
          .load("src/main/resources/sample.csv")

        init.show(10, false)
```

At some moment I had to add `org.apache.hive:hive-exec:3.1.2` dependency and got an exception during execution:

```
Illegal pattern component: XXX
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: XXX
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.parsePattern(FastDatePrinter.java:282)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.init(FastDatePrinter.java:149)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.<init>(FastDatePrinter.java:142)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.<init>(FastDateFormat.java:369)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat$1.createInstance(FastDateFormat.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat$1.createInstance(FastDateFormat.java:88)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FormatCache.getInstance(FormatCache.java:82)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.getInstance(FastDateFormat.java:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOptions.<init>(CSVOptions.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOptions.<init>(CSVOptions.scala:41)
    ...
```

It says that `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.parsePattern()` cannot parse spark timestamp format (`org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOptions.timestampFormat`) which is by default set to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"`. (Please, note that my sample.csv doesn't have any timestamp data, but anyway Spark goes through this stack of precedures).

Initially, `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter` was added to project by `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6` dependency and worked fine. However, `org.apache.hive:hive-exec:3.1.2` library has added its own implementation of specified package and class, which cannot parse `"XXX"` (and it cannot be excluded, as it is implemented inside library itself).

[image]
So I have a situation where 2 library dependencies which provide 2 realizations of the same package, and I need to chose a specific one of them during app execution. How this can be done?

> P.S. I've found a workaround for this specific "[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429616/spark-2-2-illegal-pattern-component-xxx-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-ill)" issue, but I'm more interested in how to resolve such SBT dependencies issues in general.

Comment: Remove all libraryDependencies but `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5" and start over.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, thanks for comment. When I start over, I finally come up to the same situation. Yes, if I only leave `spark-sql` it will successfully read CSV file, as it has `commons-lang3` dependency inside. But I need `hive-exec` for my further application logic. And this `hive-exec` causes the problem.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski and I tried to leave the question generic: how to deal with situation when 2 libraries add package and class with the same name, but different implementation

Comment: Can you describe why you need `hive-exec` dependency? You could define [spark-hive](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.11) dependency instead if that's something needed for Spark SQL.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, yes, actually I've initially started from `org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:2.4.5`, which transitively adds `org.spark-project.hive:hive-exec:1.2.1.spark2`. But in this case I had an exception with unsupported Hadoop version: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.1.2 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion(ShimLoader.java:174)`. That is the **only reason** why I overrode `hive-exec` dependency. I would be glad if you suggest how to overcome this without overriding `hive-exec` dependency.

Comment: Why do you need this hive-exec dependency?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I don't really need it, it is added transitively by `com.holdenkarau:spark-testing-base:2.4.5_0.14.0` which I use for unit test. But when I run tests, "Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.1.2" appears (and I found out that it goes from `org.spark-project.hive:hive-exec:1.2.1.spark2`). Basically, I don't use/need Hive and hive-exec in my application.

Comment: OK. Makes more sense now. Do you enableHiveSupport while building a SparkSession? That'd be the only case I can think of where hive-exec would be needed. It'd be nice to have a test to reproduce the issue. Holden would love it! :)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, in my test I don't build a SparkSession manually, but rather use predefined one from Holden library by extending _DatasetSuiteBase_ trait. I've gone through the code of _DataFrameSuiteBaseLike_ (where _spark_ comes from) and found that Holden enables Hive [by default](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/blob/master/core/src/main/2.0/scala/com/holdenkarau/spark/testing/DataFrameSuiteBase.scala#L62). What would you recommend? Currently it seems impossible to use Holden and `org.spark-project.hive:hive-exec` with Hadoop 3

Comment: Could you report it as an issue in the project's repo? Since you don't need hive (yet the spark-testing-base enables it) why are you saying that _"it seems impossible to use it with Hadoop 3"_? Is this needed for tests only? Why?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I meant that as soon as _spark-testing-base_ enables Hive by default (even though I don't need it), it always throws "Unrecognized Hadoop major version number" when I have Hadoop 3 in the project. So it's more like "impossible to use _spark-testing-base_ with Hadoop 3". Anyway, thanks a lot for support, I will report an issue. Returning to question: is there a way in SBT to chose specific version/implementation of class when this class is added by 2 different libraries? Would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In situation of conflicting version dependency, I usually-

1. **`Exclude certain transitive dependencies of a dependency`**
   ref - https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies
2. **`For binary conflicts like mentioned in above query, I use dependencyOverrides and override the version I want.`**
   ref- https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version
3. **`rarely, if the problem doesn't solve with above 2 options, then i'll rebuild the my own version with the compatible transitive dependency`**

PS. Please look out for other flavours of hive exec (if any) which will save you from such situations

Comment: Thanks for reply! However, these options didn't help.

1. _exclude_ doesn't help here, as there is nothing to exclude, `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter` is a direct member of `org.apache.hive:hive-exec:3.1.2`

2. I've already tried to put `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6` into _dependencyOverrides_, but again, it didn't help, the exception is still raised. And that seems right, as _dependencyOverrides_ can set certain version of one library, but I have one package from different libraries

Comment: Then i'll go for 3rd option. Updated the answer

Comment: sorry, could you please explain more detailed what do you mean by "rebuild my own version"?

Comment: I mean, while using most of the open source package, the issue is generally prompt up. I usually clone the repo do some transitive dependency version changes that is needed and build the jar. May be you can do this in this case :)