# Apache Spark Error When Reading a CSV File

Tags: scala, dataframe, csv, apache-spark

I'm trying to read a simple CSV from my local file system from my Jupyter Notebook that is running a Scala kernel.

This is what I do:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val spark = {
  NotebookSparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
}

val df = spark.read
         .format("csv")
         .option("header", "true")
         .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
         .load("/home/user/ml-projects/housing-classification-example-scala/data/file.csv")

df.printSchema()
```

This is the content of my CSV file:

```
id,name
1,joesan
2,sanjoe
```

Here is the error I get:

```
ERROR Execute exception in user code (Illegal pattern component: XXX)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: XXX
  org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.parsePattern(FastDatePrinter.java:282)
  org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.init(FastDatePrinter.java:149)
  org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.<init>(FastDatePrinter.java:142)
  org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.<init>(FastDateFormat.java:384)
  org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.<init>(FastDateFormat.java:369)
  org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat$1.createInstance(FastDateFormat.java:91)
  org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat$1.createInstance(FastDateFormat.java:88)
  org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FormatCache.getInstance(FormatCache.java:82)
  org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.getInstance(FastDateFormat.java:165)
  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOptions.<init>(CSVOptions.scala:140)
  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOptions.<init>(CSVOptions.scala:45)
  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.inferSchema(CSVFileFormat.scala:58)
  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$getOrInferFileFormatSchema$12(DataSource.scala:183)
  scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:180)
  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd1$Helper.<init>(cmd1.sc:13)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd1$.<init>(cmd1.sc:7)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd1$.<clinit>(cmd1.sc)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd1.$main(cmd1.sc)
  java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  ammonite.runtime.Evaluator$$anon$1.$anonfun$evalMain$1(Evaluator.scala:108)
  ammonite.util.Util$.withContextClassloader(Util.scala:24)
  ammonite.runtime.Evaluator$$anon$1.evalMain(Evaluator.scala:90)
  ammonite.runtime.Evaluator$$anon$1.$anonfun$processLine$2(Evaluator.scala:127)
  ammonite.util.Catching.map(Res.scala:117)
```

Comment: this might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429616/spark-2-2-illegal-pattern-component-xxx-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-ill

Comment: Should I include commons-lang3 to get this resolved?